# ¿Cuál es el origen de "en lo que cabe" o "dentro de lo que cabe"?

Tags: adverbios, expresiones

*En lo que cabe* o *dentro de lo que cabe* son locuciones que pueden ser reemplazadas por *esencialemnte* y otros adverbios:

> – ¿Cómo está tu marido, después del accidente?
>   –  Bien, dentro de lo que cabe. (= "ignorando nimiedades, está bien")

¿Cuál es el orígen de tales locuciones?

Comment: ... Good question!. No idea at all. I searched over the net, no explanation found. I´ll see if i have a book covering this topic...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Dentro de lo que cabe" viene de "Dentro de lo que cabe esperar". A su vez, "Lo que cabe esperar" es el conjunto de posibles (o más bien esperables) resultados de una acción o de un hecho natural.

Así, "dentro de lo que cabe (esperar)" implica que algo está entre los posibles resultados. Tu marido está bien, entre los posibles resultados (anímicos) del accidente. No es un bien absoluto, no está bien, sino que dentro del conjunto de posibles estados en los que podría estar, está en los mejores.

Comment: Ya veo. Pero ¿por qué el verbo *esperar*? ¿Fue alguna vez usada la expresión completa "dentro de lo que cabe esperar"?

Comment: @c.p. Sí. De hecho es una expresión utilizada todavía hoy.

Comment: http://www.eltiempo.com/opinion/columnistas/lvarovalenciatovar/ARTICULO-WEB-NEW_NOTA_INTERIOR-13008897.html

Comment: http://www.wordmagicsoft.com/diccionario/es-en/tan%20bien%20como%20cabe%20esperar.php

Comment: http://www.tripadvisor.es/ShowUserReviews-g293736-d656877-r131684661-Hotel_Rabat-Rabat_Rabat_Sale_Zemmour_Zaer_Region.html

Answer (score 1):

No parece necesario suponer que la frase completa haya requerido del verbo esperar. Según la RAE:

**caber.**
(Del lat. capĕre, coger).

> intr. Dicho de una cosa: Tocarle a alguien o pertenecerle.

y si conultamos "tocar":

**tocar**
(De la onomat. toc).

> intr. Dicho de una cosa: Caer en suerte.

por lo que:

> Dentro de lo que cabe == Dentro de lo que cae en suerte (lo que puede ser, las posibilidades)

Comment: Me gusta, +1, pero aún no la digiero. "Dentro de lo que cabe" lo mismo que "dentro de lo que toca"...

Comment: @c.p. finalmente es "dentro de lo cae en suerte" o sea, poniéndonos poéticos, "dentro de los destinos posibles"